# How to run the Yahoo webplayer?

Tags: javascript, yahoo-api, audio-player

I try to run the Yahoo webplayer like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<p><a href="song.mp3">Play Song</a></p>
<p><a href="liar.wav">Play Text</a></p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://webplayer.yahooapis.com/player.js">
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

- In Google Chrome it doesn't load at all.. (it's stuck at buffering...)
- in Firefox it tells me that Adobe Flash has stopped 'cause of "potentially unsafe operation" and it still doesn't load when I click "Ok"

Do you know how this player is supposed to work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your file names for spaces or invalid characters